# How do you send a PayPal REST API Refund in a C# Winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm finding very little documentation online for implementing the PayPal REST API in C#.

I have gotten past the first step of getting an access token, but I keep seeing conflicting methods for sending API calls and nothing I have tried works.

Here's my current code:

```
                private async void cmdRefund_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();

            string AccessToken;
            string Nonce;
            string AppID;
            string TokenType;
            try
            {
                // ClientId of your Paypal app API

                //This is the live ID
                string APIClientId = "AZxxxx-8";


                //this is the live secret Key
                string APISecret = "Exxxx39";


                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(APIClientId + ":" + APISecret);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                    //this is the live url
                    var url = new Uri("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token", UriKind.Absolute);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.UtcNow;

                    var requestParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                                {
                                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                                };

                    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestParams);
                    var webresponse = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                    var resp = await webresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    MessageBox.Show(resp);
                    if (resp.IndexOf("access_token") == -1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("PayPal Authorization Failed.");
                        return;
                    }
                    AccessToken = resp.Substring(resp.IndexOf("access_token") + 15);
                    AccessToken = AccessToken.Substring(0, AccessToken.IndexOf("\""));

                    Nonce = resp.Substring(resp.IndexOf("nonce") + 8);
                    Nonce = Nonce.Substring(0, Nonce.IndexOf("\""));
                    AppID = resp.Substring(resp.IndexOf("app_id") + 9);
                    AppID = AppID.Substring(0, AppID.IndexOf("\""));
                    TokenType = resp.Substring(resp.IndexOf("token_type") + 13);
                    TokenType = TokenType.Substring(0, TokenType.IndexOf("\""));
                    MessageBox.Show("Access Token: \r\n" + AccessToken + "\r\nNonce:\r\n" + Nonce + "\r\nAppID:\r\n" + AppID + "\r\nToken Type:\r\n" + TokenType);
                    // response will deserialized using Jsonconver
                    //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PayPalGetTokenResponse>(resp);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    return;
                }
                //Authorization has been achieved here - now I want to process a refund
                    var apiContext = new APIContext(AccessToken);

            Amount refundAmount = new Amount();
            refundAmount.total = "0.01";
            refundAmount.currency = "USD";

            Refund refund = new Refund();
            refund.amount = refundAmount;
            string saleId = "9XY489008U7836633";

   //*************THIS NEXT LINE CAUSES AN ERROR

            Refund refundforreal = Sale.Refund(apiContext, saleId, refund);
   //*************  

            string refundId = refund.id;


                }
```

The last line causes the Error: "PayPal.IdentityException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'"

As far as I can tell, my access token is completely valid, but this does not work. I should note that I the transactions I'm trying to get information on and refund are NOT placed via the REST API, but are simply placed through the regular PayPal interface integrated on our website. I don't know if that causes a problem or not, but that is what I need to do.

I am using a Windows Forms App written in C# in Visual Studios 2017 because I'm replacing an old VB6 program that required that the user log into a PayPal session in a browser in the program and need to replace that program with something that is both usable and familiar for our employees, AND is more forward thinking by using the REST API instead of the old method of filling in fields in a WebBrowser control.

***********EDIT************ - I added this as a follow up:

I took @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy's advice and used Postman and managed to do what I wanted, so thank  you - that did help me to know that at least what I want to do is possible.

I still don't know how to do the POST in C#. I think perhaps I'll stay away from the built in "Refund" object in the SDK and instead try to POST some other way.

The url I'm using is in Postman is: https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9XY489008U7836633/refund

I sent this as the body to do a $0.01 refund on my test transaction:
{
  "amount": {
  "total": "0.01",
  "currency": "USD"
  },
  "invoice_number": "INV-1234567"
}'

I added a Bearer Token authorization to the POST with my Access Token that I had from my working code.

Finally, in Postman, I changed the body from "Text" to "JSON (application/json).

How do I incorporate all these elements (the URL, my bearer token, the body, and the information that the body is json) into a POST in a C# winforms application?

Comment: have you tried to make a request in program agnostic way - say using Postman or advanced rest client. this will help in ruling out any issues with the actual request or api token or things like that. try with a simple request first. once that is successful then you can work on actual request. i don't have a handy token to try and help you specifically.

Comment: Thank you @shamanthGowdraShankaramurthy, took your advice and managed to get this to work in Postman - can you take a look at the edits I've made above and lead me in the right direction to do the POST? Would I use HttpClient?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for this, the answer turned out to be much simpler than I figured. I think I was messing myself up by not using the AccessTokens that are easily obtained by the PayPal SDK.

First, make sure that you have the App.Config file set up properly:

```
<!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
//specify sandbox or live
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox" /> 
      <add name="clientId" value="insert_clientid_key_here" />
      <add name="clientSecret" value="Insert_client_secret_key_here" />
    </settings>
  </paypal>
```

Then this is all the code I needed to make the refunds work:

```
    private void cmdRefund_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        Amount refundAmount = new Amount();
        refundAmount.total = "0.01";
        refundAmount.currency = "USD";
        RefundRequest refund = new RefundRefundRequest();
        refund.amount = refundAmount;
        string saleId = "9XY489008U7836633";
        Refund refundforreal = Sale.Refund(apiContext, saleId, refund);
        MessageBox.Show("Refund status:" + refundforreal.state + "\r\n" + "Txn #:" + refundforreal.id);
    }
```